# Java InstanceOf Output

Tags: java, inheritance, instanceof

I would like to understand how instanceof works.

Consider the following code:

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }
class D extends C { }

public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        B b = new C();   //1
        A a = b;        //2
        if (a instanceof A) System.out.println("A"); //3
        if (a instanceof B) System.out.println("B"); //4
        if (a instanceof C) System.out.println("C"); //5
        if (a instanceof D) System.out.println("D"); //6
    }
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong here, in order for *instanceof* to return true, the IS-A condition must be satisfied. If you take a look at line //1. At runtime, the program knows that the object denoted by reference "a" is of type C. Therefore, shouldn't only condition at line //5 be in the output? Why are A and B also in the output?

D not being displayed is because the object is not an instance of D and so there's no confusion there. But I don't understand why A and B are displayed in the console.

Comment: `a` is an `A` because `C extends B extends A`. `a` is an `B` because `C extends B`. `a` is a `C` because, well, it is. `a` is _not_ a `D` because `D extends C` and `a` is a `C`.

Comment: I am upvoting the question to remedy the down-votes.

Comment: @LajosArpad [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408/2071828). In short, upvote because **you** think this post is useful and deserves an upvote. Do not upvote to "reverse downvotes".

Comment: @Jeese James, An object of a class is `instanceof` all the super classes in the hierarchy (till Object.java) and also for all the interfaces implemented by it and by the super classes in the hierarchy.  I have included the various cases for `instanceof`. Hopefully it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact each reference of a certain class must reference to an object instance to that class.

That means that you can do things like `B b = new C();` because C is a subclass of B, therefore every instance of C are also instance of B.

Think of those as a matrioska doll. Every inner doll is a super-class, and the outer is a derived class.

Everytime you instantiate an object of a certain type, you duplicate the doll, but to duplicate a big doll you must also duplicate the smaller dolls that are inside.

The same way, you can think of the object as a block of memory which has everything is in its class, plus everything is in its super class, and so on till you get up to the `Object` class.

Comment: This is _very_ unlear. "_instance of C are also instance of C_" - what? "_instantiate an object of a certain type, you duplicate the doll_" - what?

Comment: The first one is a type, which i corrected now. The second is an analogy, maybe not expressed in the best way i guess, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since `C` extends `B` and `B` extends `C`, `a` is an `instanceof` `A`.

Since `C` extends `B`, `a` is an `instanceof` `B`.

It is trivial that `a` is an `instanceof` `C`.

Let me put this into context. Let's suppose that you have three `class`es, `Animal`, `CarnvorousAnimal` and `Lion`. `CarnivorousAnimal extends Animal` and `Lion extends CarnivorousAnimal`. When you instantiate a `Lion`, your `Lion` will be an `instanceof` `Lion` trivially, but it will be an `instanceof` `CarnivorousAnimal`, since every `Lion` is also a `CarnivorousAnimal`. Since your object is a `CarnivorousAnimal`, it will be an `Animal` as well, because every `CarnivorousAnimal` is an `Animal` as well.

When you extend your classes, your subclass will be a more exact specification. Something more specific is the instance of its more general definition, a subset, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator)

> An object of subclass type is also a type of parent class.

The java rule is

> A SuperClass reference variable can hold the object of SubClass.

So  your Class A is holding reference of Class B and
Class B is holding reference of  Class C.

```
Animal                             Class A

DomesticAnimal extends Animal      Class B extends A

Dog extends DomesticAnimal         Class C extends B
```

From the above table we can say **Dog is an Domestic Animal** and also **is an Animal**

**An animal is also a Animal**

simply **Class A can be a instance of Class A**

Comment: You could upvote my (earlier, equivalent) answer, as I have upvoted yours.

Answer (score 0):

All the java objects are `instanceof` Object.java So any Object when used with `instanceof` keyword returns `true` for `Object`. This is because all the java classes are derived from Object.java ( all classes are implicitly sub claases or child classes of Object.java class ).

Keyword `instanceof` returns true for

1. an object for its class
2. and for all the upper level parent classes
3. and for all the interfaces implemented by the class of the object and by all the classes in upper hierarchy of the class. Also true is returned for all the higher level interfaces (interfaces extended by the ones which are implemented)

   `public class GrandParent implements IGrandParent {
      ....
   }`

   `public class Parent implements IParent{
      ....
   }`

   `public class Child implements IChild {
      ....
   }`

   `public interface IgrandParent extends ISpecial1,ISpecial2  {
       .....
   }`

Now we see Child.java `inherits` from `ISpecial1`, `ISpecial2`, `GrandParent`, `Parent`, `IParent`, `IGrandParent` and `IChild` and hence `instanceof` for objcet of Child.java will evaluate to true for all above classes and interface, including fir Child.java.